# Loop over star shape in grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

Im using python 3,
I have a 9 * 9 list or grid that the top left corner is (0, 0) and bottom right is (8, 8)

I want to only loop over each item on that grid that is 4 cells or less away from the center (4, 4),

and preform an action on that cell.

[image]

this is my current code for this (not working)-

```
for row in range(9):
    amount = row * 2 + 1
    for col in range(9):
        if amount == 0:
            continue
        print("Col- ", col + 4 -(row % 4), "Row- ", row)
        amount -= 1
```

Comment: added my current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i succeeded in looping only through the blue square and here's my code:

```
import numpy as np


def index_generator(grid_dim):
    center = grid_dim//2
    dx = center + 1
    sx = center

    while(dx > 0 and sx < grid_dim):
        dx -= 1
        sx += 1
        yield range(dx, sx)

    while(dx <= (center) and sx >= (center + 1)):
        dx += 1
        sx -= 1
        yield range(dx, sx)


grid_dim = 9

A = np.zeros((grid_dim, grid_dim))

for r, i in zip(index_generator(grid_dim), range(grid_dim)):
    for j in r:
        A[i, j] = 1

print(A)
```

and the output is:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

I used a generator to construct the index of every row and than loop through that, in the first part i find the center and declare two delimiter (sx and dx). than i loop moving the delimiter until it reach the border of the matrix and than i just do de same thing but moving toward the center.

hope it help.

Comment: i used numpy just for convenience on declaring the matrix, it should be insignificant.

Comment: Wow that smart, I thought that maybe a shorter solution might be possible but this is great too thanks a lot! :D